# Can I select a details page within a hierarchical UITableView structure programmatically?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have the following problem, where I can't find a feasable solution.

I have a hierarchical data model using CoreData which in general represents an product catalog with categories and products. The user can navigate through the structure (CategoryList -> SubCategoryList -> ProductList -> ProductDetail page) manually without any problems.

Here comes the BUT!
We have a page with featured products. What we want to do is, if a user taps on a featured product, the tab should switch to the catalog (works just fine) and the details view for the selected product should be show (also works fine by just creating the detailsViewCotroller and push it onto the stack), BUT within the category context (I have no idea how to do that). So, the user should have possibility to tap the "Back" button in the navbar of the details view and all the subcategories and categories should be in place for browsing.

Is this even possible to manage? Again, I'm using CoreData for the model with a parent property. Any ideas or suggestions how to build up the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the category and subcategories that the featured product belongs to, you can use the navigation controller method setViewControllers:animated:, and pass in an array of controllers, one for category, one for subcategory, and one for the details. You would fetch the data for these the same way you do now.

Comment: Hm, this is such a pragmatic approach, I didn't thought of that. :-) I will try this on monday!